# Non-principal ideal in a ring which is not a domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I can easily prove that $(2,X) $ is not a principal ideal in $\mathbb Z [X] $. To do this, I use the properties of the degree.

How can one prove that $(2,X) $ is not a principal ideal in $\mathbb Z /6\mathbb Z  [X] $ ?

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb Z_6[X]/(2,X)\simeq\mathbb Z_2$ (the field with two elements); $\mathbb Z_6[X]/(f)\simeq\mathbb Z_2[X]/(f)\times\mathbb Z_3[X]/(f)$

Comment: Your second hint is the Chinese remainder theorem ?

Comment: I think user26857 intends you to discover that $(2,x)$ **IS** principal in $\mathbb Z_6[x]$. To find $f$ so that $(2,x)=(f)$, you want $f$ so that $\mathbb Z_2\cong \mathbb Z_6[x]/(2,x)=\mathbb Z_6[x]/(f)\cong \mathbb Z_2[x]/(f)\times \mathbb Z_3[x]/(f)$.  For this, apply the CRT to the congruences $f\equiv x\pmod{2}$ and $f\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

Comment: Thank you very much ! $(3x+4)\cdot 2 = 2$ and $(3x+4)\cdot(4x+3) = x $ :)

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z_6 [X] $ actually a principal ideal ring ?

Comment: @Friedrich Yes: it’s the product of $F_2[X]$ and $F_3[X]$.